# How to start Android Device File Explorer without Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, react-native, android-device-explorer

I am building my app with React Native and do not need Android Studio. I am starting the emulator directly from console. However if I need to check files, I always need to start Android Studio to launch the Device File Explorer.

Can I launch the Device File Explorer directly from console or as standalone in some way?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry, that specific tool is an integrated part of Android Studio.

There used to be the Dalvik Debug Monitor Service (DDMS), which was a standalone tool that had a file explorer among other things. Google discontinued that some time ago.

The only official solution that I can think of is to use `adb pull` from the command line.

Otherwise, you would need to see if somebody created a standalone tool for this, or perhaps a plugin for [Sonar](https://fbsonar.com/).

Comment: I think they removed it from Android Studio.  It's no longer listed in the Tools Windows.